# Compare every value of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data with 1000 rows and 20 columns, and I would like to group by value some row.

Here an example of what I have :

```
column A   column B  column C  column D   column E

XX        YY         25/01/2022   25         50
XX        YY         17/01/2023   32         10
```

I would like group by per column A and column B and sum value of column D and column E

Here an example of what I want :

```
column A   column B  column C  column D   column E

XX        YY         25/01/2022   57        60
```

I kept the inferior date .
I would like do it in python with pandas maybe.

Thanks for reading me.

if I need group by only when column A is XX, what could I add for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.groupby()` and aggregation `first` for column `C` and `sum` for columns `D` and `E`.

```
data = {'A': ['XX', 'XX'], 'B': ['YY', 'YY'],
        'C':['25/01/2022', '17/01/2023'],
        'D': [25, 32], 'E': [50, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df.A == 'XX'].groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).agg({'C':'first','D':'sum','E':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
    A   B           C   D   E
0  XX  YY  25/01/2022  57  60
```

Comment: sry I was eating,  thx, I try it and I come back to you !

Comment: no problem! I hope it works the way you want to

Comment: ok it worked perfectly !  I would like to do smth else with this code if possible   I edit my post

Comment: You can use as_index=False in groupby

Comment: @seb you can add `df.A == 'XX'`. Do you want to remove the other rows or group by only these rows and add the others? If the latter: name the dataframe above `df1` and concatenate the other rows.

Comment: @seb if this answers your question, could you mark it as so?